# Can I add 2 different button classes' in a trigger under the main tag and get proper data in my GA?

Tags: triggers, tags, google-tag-manager

In a pricing page, there is a "Buy" button when user clicks on the button, it takes to a page where the user chooses payment type and again there is a button with another class, I want to track both of them. Is it possible to set up 2 button classes(in one trigger) under the button click tag and get proper data in GA?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, but not in this way, as visible on your screenshot. These conditions have AND relation. So your current trigger requires a click on an element with a class containing `payment-button price-btn` AND `btn-pay` at the same time.

So you need to create two separate triggers for the two class variants, and attach both of them to the same tag as firing triggers, as those will have OR condition among themselves.

Please note, that `payment-button price-btn` will look for this string. So if there's any chance, that the classes don't appear in this exact order, you might want to go for just one of them, or separate these two classes in two rows of one trigger, `payment-button` and `price-btn`.